# Change UITextField.text from an external class swift

Tags: swift, class

I'm trying to simplify my life by dividing chunk of related code into different classes.

But I encounter a problem: changing the ViewController property (like UITextField.text, etc.) from those classes.

I have tried creating protocol, but that was really messy so I want to find a new way to do this.

So, is there a simple way to change ViewController property directly from external classes? I'm using Swift 3 btw.

Thank y'all for helping.

Comment: You can add a public method where you inject the text,something like "func update(name:String){...modify the label text here}", you don't have to access the UILabel directy.

Comment: Can u be more specific? I'm not very well at Swift

Answer (score 0):

If the object from where you want to change your label is a child object owned or presented by the controller, than you need to use delegation to comunicate back with the controller. You declare a protocol in that object from where you want to change the controller's label, and declare a weak property of that protocol type called delegate. When the controller creates that object you will set that object's delegate property to the controller itself (If that object is ownee by the controller, declaring the property weak you will not create a retain cycle). In the controller you implement the method declared in the protocol and in the implementation you can change the label.
The other case when the controller is owned or presented by the object from where you wanna change the label, in yhis case you just need a public method to do that.